# How do we configure another browser to use Tor?

Tags: browser, proxy, privacy, tor

How do we configure Google Chrome (or another web browser) to use Tor Browser?

By that I mean that we are using Chrome, but the traffic is routed through Tor (and thus anonymous).

Comment: You should maybe [read the Tor documentation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-windows.html.en).

Comment: Judging by this question, I think you are currently in over your head on this subject. (You'd aim to set Chrome up to use a proxy, not get 'Tor Browser' to use another browser).  Why not go read up on it, try a few things, and then come back with specific, answerable questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Download OperaTOR from [here](http://archetwist.com/opera/operator).
2. Install OperaTOR - a TOR client for the Opera browser.
3. Verify that TOR is working correctly using the pre-installed bookmark "`Are you using Tor?`
4. Start Google Chrome.
5. Using the Tools menus (it looks like a wrench), choose options, "Under the hood". Scroll down to "Network" and click the "Change Proxy Setting" button.
6. Under the "Connections" tab, choose "LAN Setting" - Select Use Proxy server and enter "Localhost" and port 8118.
7. Save your work and return to the Chrome web browser. Check that you are using TOR by going [here](http://check.torproject.org/).
8. A Green message will indicate that TOR is operating correctly. A Red message will indicate that TOR is not set up correctly.
9. Continue to surf using TOR

References:

- [How to configure Google Chrome for Tor](http://justplainobvious.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-configure-google-chrome-for-tor.html)
- [How to configure Google Chrome to Tor](http://pcmgz.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-do-you-configure-google-chrome-to.html)

Comment: I added the link you first had in your answer again, seemed like a better resource. It should also be noted that steps 1-3 don't need to be done if Tor is already installed and manually [switching with Proxy Switchy](http://lifehacker.com/5614732/create-a-tor-button-in-chrome-for-on+demand-anonymous-browsing) is a bit more comfortable.

Comment: link/domain is dead for 1.

Comment: OperaTOR link is dead

Answer (score 7):

*This is for GNU/Linux*

I have a script, `chromium-tor`, that boots Chromium already connected to a running Tor daemon. On any Ubuntu/Debian system,

```
sudo apt-get install vidalia
```

will install Vidalia, an easy Tor admin interface. Run Vidalia (`alt-F2`, run "vidalia") and wait for it to give you the all-go. Then run this line:

```
chromium --proxy-server="socks://localhost:9050"
```

depending on whatever your distro's binary is for Chrome or whether or not you use Chromium, you may have to modify that line. This should work.

To run as a single command, make a file `/usr/bin/chromium-tor` (you'll need root privileges to do so)

```
#!/bin/bash

chromium --proxy-server="socks://localhost:9050"
```

If you use `google-chrome` for your binary, `google-chrome-tor` for the name would be better, and replace chromium with `google-chrome` in the script. You'll also need to do

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/chromium-tor
```

before it will work.

Edit:  For Ubuntu, use `chromium-browser` instead of `chromium` in `/usr/bin/chromium-tor` and sometimes port number 9150 is also used.

```
#!/bin/bash

chromium-browser --proxy-server="socks://localhost:9050"
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Download [Advanced Onion routing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/) and run it.
2. Click connect.
3. Then, in Chrome, go to the Tools menu, and then the Under the hood tab. Scroll to network, and click Change proxy settings.
4. Under connections, select LAN, IP is 127.0.0.1 port is 9050.
5. Save, and surf normally.