# How can I make Tor route all my traffic?

Tags: tor

How can I set Tor to route all of my internet traffic? So, if I want to use any program to connect to a website or send requests to it, is there any way that I can make Tor hide my IP at all times?

Comment: What is the operating system used and is this going to include the kernel level network calls, such as phone home calls to check for updates, or is this going to apply to only the application layer of the user space?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324685/how-to-route-all-internet-traffic-through-tor-the-onion-router

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use Tortilla is a program designed to create a virtual adapter which uses only tor connection, the program is here https://github.com/CrowdStrike/Tortilla

Answer (score 4):

This is a near-identical question to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/316851/how-do-we-configure-another-browser-to-use-tor).  In the program you're looking to redirect, find the setting for defining a 'proxy', and use IP 127.0.0.1 (or 'localhost) and port 8118.

Comment: That being answered, you _may not want to_.  Vidalia includes a browser configured with settings, protocols, along with certain features removed to cover 'holes' in a normal network-application's use.  If you feel the need to ask this, then you shouldn't feel confident that you'll be secure.  As @Keltari noted, Tor's [article](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea) is a good explanation as to why you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the Tor Browser then go into your network settings and tell all network activity to go through the Tor proxy then that theoretically should do it.

Like in this how to: http://www.wikihow.com/Route-All-Network-Traffic-Through-the-Tor-Network

Answer (score 1):

You really wouldnt want to.  Tor is an *extremely slow* network, designed for viewing web pages anonymously (with lots of caveats).  Also, there is no guarantee that your application would keep your anonymity.  A perfect example of ***not*** running other applications through Tor's network is explained by this [article](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea) from the developers of Tor.

Comment: This is better-stated as a comment than an answer, however wise this statement is.

Comment: -1. This does not answer the question.

Comment: +1. I disagree wit those stating this should not be an answer, If there is no way to do something with the effect the OP would like to achieve (in this case, a reasonable assurance of anonimity), then there is **no** good way to do it, and to point out that this is so is a better answer than providing a recipe which is leaking from its every pore.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae there are legitimate reasons for wanting to do this, so this answer is just a comment. Whether or not it's sage advice in most situations is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

This scripts seems to be exactly what you're looking for:

https://github.com/GouveaHeitor/nipe

> This Perl Script enables you to directly route all your traffic from
>   your computer to the Tor Network ...

Answer (score 0):

You can build an onion router with a raspberry pi. Then you would have your own network, which directs everything through the tor network

Or you can order it from adafruit.com.

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1406

Maybe a little late, but useful for people who still have the same question

So ip leaks are excluded. I also use it when I do stuff again.

And if you don't want your packages to be intercepted, I would also recommend a usb ethernet adapter

Answer (score 0):

For windows:

1. Download and run TorBrowser
2. Connect TorBrowser to some tor server
3. Open Control panel, find there Internet Options and open it
4. On Connections tab open LAN settings choose "Use a proxy server...", then open Advanced settings and specify in Socks: 127.0.0.1 : 9150

[image]

But I am not sure if it can redirect all traffic through tor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Torifier**.

> "Torifier lets you tunnel software applications through Tor without the need to reconfigure them."

It seems the Torifier website is gone, but you can still [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20220625192904/https://torifier.com/download.html) the program from [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20220816170829/https://torifier.com/) for example.

UPDATE Oct.2023: The website is back up again: https://www.torifier.com

[image]